# Error analysing JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON file (defined as `k` in my code) that has multiple levels within it I'm trying to analyse and am getting an error I'm having trouble understanding.

Here is my code as it is:

```
for i in k:
    if 'pens' in k[i]:
    print i+"       "+str(k[i]['pens']['Papermate']['Total Quantity'])
```

I am getting the below error

`KeyError: 'Papermate'`

when it has reached an `i` such that `pens` is not in `k[i]` at all, but does have `'Papermate'` directly in `k[i]` (ie. not within `'pens'`).

What I want to happen in this case is for it to skip `k[i]` altogether and not print anything.

How would I do that?

Comment: you need to show the json. By the sounds of things you are trying to access things that arent there but your description isnt particularly clear. Is `Papermate` within `pens` or within `i`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `pformat`

```
from pprint import pformat
import json
k = json.load(yourfile.json)
for i in k:
    pformat(i)
```

`pformat` show to our console all data and you check the problem because python no detect `'Papermate'` key.

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing looks like it should work but it depends on how you are parsing the json. This would be how I would code it based on your description

```
import json

k = json.load(yourfile.json)
for i in k:
    if 'pens' in i.iterkeys():
        print i+"       "+str(i['pens']['Papermate']['Total Quantity'])
```

but without seeing the actual `json` its hard to know.

Comment: I only want it to print the Papermates that are within `pens` (it appears both within `pens` and `i`). If I'm reading your code right this will print it in both cases. It's working fine right now when it is in both (ie only printing the one in `pens`) and skipping over the ones where there is no `pens` and no `Papermate` in `i` either which is what I want to happen in those cases. The only situation where I'm getting the error is when `pens` is not there but `Papermate` still appears in `i` (and what I want it to do in this case is skip it and print nothing). Thanks.

Comment: made a slight edit to code and removed else statement and that should work.

Comment: I get this error on line 2: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'

Comment: how are you parsing the json? can you show the json?